# Kodi plugin and URL with basic authentication

Tags: plugins, basic-authentication, add-on, kodi

I'm writing KODI plugin, where I'm trying to play resources from external service. Access of resources requires basic authentication.

I was following [this](http://kodi.wiki/view/Audio-video_add-on_tutorial) tutorial of how to write add-on. They call addDirectoryItem method in xbmcplugin.

```
url = 'http://localhost/some_video.mkv'
li = xbmcgui.ListItem(foldername + ' Video', iconImage='DefaultVideo.png')
xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=addon_handle, url=url, listitem=li)
```

It accepts url as string. I cannot find any option, how to do authentication part.

Answer (score 0):

Kodi player allows to pass custom HTTP headers, including authentication headers, to a remote server like the following:

```
from urllib import quote

url = 'http://some.server/video.mkv|Header1={0}&Header2={1}'.format(
quote(header1_value),
quote(header2_value)
)
```

That is, after a pipe `|` you can pass a set of `header=value` pairs separated by `&`. Header values must be URL-quoted.